# Resque: How to calculate how many workers I can spin up on a machine?

Tags: ruby, resque

I realized I can spin up up to 41 resque workers on my Macbook air. How do I calculate how many I can spin up on an arbitrary machine?

And is spinning up as many workers as possible optimal?

Comment: As with all benchmarking: Try and measure.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Which measuring tools / which parameters to monitor?

Comment: I benchmarked my code by wrapping the task that my worker was running in a `time = Benchmark.start do` block and saving the seconds elapsed (and other data) to a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what the workers are doing I think.

For example I have a rails app that processes images using RMagick/Resque.

On my Intel Quad Core Q9300 CPU with 4GB of RAM (machine specs do probably matter!) I processed 100 images, several different times, with 1,2 and 5 workers. Here is some of the data:

1 worker, time elapsed 1:35 average processing time per image - 0.89949550366 (seconds)

2 workers, time elapsed 1:13 average processing time per image - 1.41478641043 (seconds)

5 workers, time elapsed 1:13 average processing time per image - 3.22651901574 (seconds)

As you can see, workers do have diminishing returns on them. But it does probably scale based off of the task you are having your workers do.